# reactRouter2.default undefined using Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, babeljs

I have created a universal React app based on [this tutorial](http://blog.lunarlogic.io/2015/how-to-create-a-universal-reactjs-application-with-bare-reactjs/) however I'm getting

```
'Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).'
```

in Chrome Dev tools. Looking at the compiled code I can see an object which is undefined - `_reactRouter2.default`. On the surface everything seems to be working ok, I can navigate between pages, I can use the back button in the browser, but I don't understand that error. Can anyone shed some light on how I might fix it?

Here is a screenshot showing how `_reactRouter2.default` is constructed and that it is undefined. [image: Screenshot of router construction]

Here are some relevant code snippets:

[**src/routes.js**](https://github.com/stuartleyland/packed-it-webapp/blob/master/src/routes.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';

import Main from './components/Main.js';
import Login from './components/Login.js';
import ListsOverview from './components/ListsOverview.js';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={Main}>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/overview" component={ListsOverview} />
  </Route>
);
```

[**src/application.js**](https://github.com/stuartleyland/packed-it-webapp/blob/master/src/application.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Router from 'react-router';
import Routes from './routes';

import { createHistory } from 'history'

const history = createHistory()

var app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history} routes={Routes} />, app);
```

[**server.js**](https://github.com/stuartleyland/packed-it-webapp/blob/master/server.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import Express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import Routes from './src/routes';
import Webpack from 'webpack';
import WebpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import DefaultConfig from './webpack/default.config.js';
import DevConfig from './webpack/development.config.js';

let app = Express();
let port = process.env.PORT || DefaultConfig.Port;
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(Express.static(DefaultConfig.Dist));

if (isDevelopment) {
  const compiler = Webpack(DevConfig);
  app.use(WebpackMiddleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: DevConfig.output.publicPath,
    noInfo: true
  }));
}

if (isProduction) {
  app.set('views', DefaultConfig.Dist);
}

app.use((req, res) => {
  match({ routes: Routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (renderProps) {
      res.render('index', {
        isDevelopment: isDevelopment,
        app: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />)
      });
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Not found');
    }
  })
});

http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

[**package.json**](https://github.com/stuartleyland/packed-it-webapp/blob/master/package.json)

```
{
  "name": "packed-it",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Application for managing packing lists",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node -- server.js",
    "build": "rimraf dist && NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack/production.config.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "production": "NODE_ENV=production npm start"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@github.com/stuartleyland/packed-it.git"
  },
  "author": "Stuart Leyland",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/stuartleyland/packed-it/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/stuartleyland/packed-it#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.4.2",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "history": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2",
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
    "react-router": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.19.0",
    "node-jsx": "^0.13.3",
    "npm-watch": "^0.1.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1"
  }
}
```

All of the code is available in [this Github repository](https://github.com/stuartleyland/packed-it-webapp) in case I've missed anything relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's probably happening because you are not importing the **Router** properly.

this

src/application.js

```
import Router from 'react-router';
```

should be

```
import { Router } from 'react-router'
```

[React Router Documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/02-rendering-a-route#rendering-a-route)

Comment: That was it - thank you! After fixing this I received an error about passing a deprecated history object to the router. I fixed this by following [these instructions](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls). Thanks again!